# VB.Net Web Method giving a HTTP401 Not Authorised error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis

I use web methods in a couple of places in the intranet site im working on and they work fine, however one page is constantly throwing a HTTP 401 error every time I try access the web method.

Im not sure how to aproach this issue, I have tried commenting everything out of the web method, and still get the 401 error, even a basic connect to the database just doing `SELECT 1` does not show up when I watch the DB with profiler.

My web.config is the same for all pages in the intranet and I cannot see any differences in my ASP.Net page compared to pages where web methods work.

Can anyone tell me why this could be happening for just this page and not others? And also how can I get around this problem?

The ASP.Net Code (called from the OnClientClick of a button)

```
   function SendEmails()
   {

      var Grid = document.getElementById("instructorGrid");
      var mailBody = document.getElementById("txtMailBody");
      var ddlDutyPeriod = document.getElementById("DDL_DutyPeriods");

         var cell = Grid.rows[i].cells;
         var HTML = cell[0].innerHTML;
         var chkBox = cell[5].innerHTML;

         PageMethods.TestMethod()
   }
```

The script manager

```
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" 
                         runat="server" 
                         EnableScriptGlobalization="true"
                         EnablePageMethods="true" 
                         EnableScriptLocalization="true">
  </asp:ScriptManager>
```

The VB.Net Code

```
  <System.Web.Services.WebMethod()>
   Public Shared Sub TestMethod()

      'Dim conn1 As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Blueprint").ToString())

      'Dim cmd2 As New SqlCommand

      'cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.Text
      'cmd2.CommandText = "SELECT 1"


      'cmd2.Connection = conn1

      'conn1.Open()
      'cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
      'conn1.Close()

   End Sub
```

The Fiddler results

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Not Authorized</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Not Authorized</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 401. The requested resource requires user authentication.</p>
</BODY></HTML>
```

UPDATE:

I have tried using impersonating the user in code like half way down in this link http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306158 however I cant do that since the method is a webmethod.

I have also tried adding anonymous access to my login page in web.config as suggested below but this also hasnt helped

Comment: Does IIS have access rights to the file you're trying to access. (NTFS-Level access). As the Service is run by IIS you'll need to grant access to the Application Pool User (or Users). Try adding IIS_IUSRS Group with full access.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are using FormsAuthentication.  You must give your login page anonymous access.

```
<location path="Login.aspx">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: Would this just affect this one page though, I use web methods on other pages within the same website and they work fine.

Comment: I had the same thing happen to me just last week.  I didn't delve into figuring out why it was happening for one page and not another.  Also, adding anonymous access to your log in page is recommended and make sense.

Comment: Tried but this doesnt seem to help. Does it matter that the site is a mixture of Classic and .Net   the login I think is in classic.

Answer (score 2):

Add the impersonation tag in your web.config file.  This should allow impersonation with a specific account when trying to access your web method.  See this support [article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306158) for direction.

```
<system.web>

<identity impersonate="true" userName="Yang" password="bar" />

</system.web>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a long shot but do you have this in your Web.Config?

```
<system.web.extensions>
  <scripting>
    <webServices>
      <authenticationService enabled="true" />
    </webServices>
  </scripting>
</system.web.extensions>
```

Comment: I have had this problem before and adding that resolved it - I managed to find a link which explained it but can't find it now (will post if I come across it)